# Android 13 Push notification and device registration in react native

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I am implementing Push Notification in both Android and iOS in React Native. I am using `react-native-firebase/app` `react-native-firebase/messaging` and `notifee`. In iOS device are automatically registered for push notification and that can be disable by `messaging_ios_auto_register_for_remote_messages`. And, react-native-firebase has methods that can be used to register and unregister device in iOS.

Android 13 now also has the option to to reject and allow permission. My question is, does the device still auto registered in Android 13 even if the permission is not given for push notification? `messaging().unregisterDeviceForRemoteMessages()` dosent seems to be working in android.